# Verify that T is a binary tree

Tags: algorithms

Given a tree, how efficiently can you verify whether T is a binary search tree or not?
 I really do not know how to proceed with this. I think an algorithm is required, but I cannot figure out any... Please help

Comment: I suppose that the root of the tree is given also. I would verify "binariness" by slightly modified DFS, starting in the root. DFS itself tells whether there are any cycles in the tree or not and whether your graph is connected. If you add a counter of nodes that are visited directly after the current node, this counter must equal $0$ (in the case the current node is a leaf) or $1$ or $2$ (in the case the current node is not a leaf).

Comment: Is the tree finite? Because in binary trees, each node has at most 2 children

Comment: finite it is....

Comment: Antoine, can u please elaborate? did not quite understand, (sorry for my dumbness, i am a slow learner)

Comment: @user3237995 Have you heard of DFS?

Comment: yes yes! depth first search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will write down modified version of DFS, which I have [copied from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode). Let be $T$ your graph. Let's assume that you are given that $T$ is a [simple graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29#Simple_graph). The following algorithm $\bf{isBinaryTree(graph\; G,\; vertex \; v)}$ returns $\bf{True}$ if a "subtree" (of the graph $\bf{G}$) whose "root" is $\bf{v}$, is a binary tree, and $\bf{False}$ otherwise. Quotation marks around the words "subtree" and "root" were used, since these terms are well defined only if a graph is a tree indeed. In the following pseudocode, standard notation is used: == means "equals", != means "doesn't equal" and || means logical OR.

```
 1 procedure isBinaryTree(G, v):
 2     label v as discovered
 3     v.directSuccessors = 0
 4     for all edges vw in Edges(G):
 5         if (vertex w is not labeled as discovered):
 6             v.directSuccessors = v.directSuccessors + 1
 7             w.predecessor = v
 8             if (isBinaryTree(G, w) == False):
 9                 return False
10         else if (v.predecessor != w):
11             return False
12     if (v.directSuccessors > 2):
13         return False
14     else if (v.predecessor is undefined):
15         if (there is an undiscovered vertex in T):
16             return False
17         else:
18             return True
19     else:
20         return True
```

How to use the algorithm? If you are given a candidate for root also, all you have to do, is to call $\bf{isBinaryTree(T,\; rootT)}$. If this is not the case, just find a vertex $\bf{rootT}$ of degree $\deg ({\bf{rootT}})\leq 2$ and then call $\bf{isBinaryTree(T,\; rootT)}$.

We should prove that the algorithm returns $\bf{True}$ if and only if a graph $G$ is connected and does not contain any cycles. I won't write down full-detailed proof. Instead, let's just make some notes.

**Connectedness:**
Take a look at the last if-else if-else block. In the $15$th line we test whether  we have visited all the vertices (else if), i. e. graph $G$ is connected. Note that the condition

> $\bf{v.predecessor}$  is undefined

in the $14$th line is tested only on the vertices $\bf{v}$ that have been visited and is therefore fulfilled if and only if the vertex $\bf{v}$ is our candidate for the root of $T$. Hence connectedness of the graph $G$ is tested exactly once (which is important, since it could be time-consuming) and after it is tested, no additional vertices are processed.

**Having no cycles:**
This is handled in the $10$th line. If $\bf{v.predecessor != w}$ equals $\bf{True}$ (the case that the predecessor of $\bf{v}$ is undefined is included here), we have discovered a cycle in our graph:

> $\bf{v}$, $\bf{v.predecessor}$, $\bf{v.predecessor.predecessor}$, ... , $\bf{w}$, $\bf{v}$

The upper list is indeed a cycle since it contains at least $3$ different vertices: $\bf{v}$, $\bf{v.predecessor}$ and $\bf{w}$.

**Being binary:**
This is handled in the $12$th line.

**Additional note:**
If at the some point, $\bf{isBinaryTree(T,\; w)}$ equals $\bf{False}$, then due to the $8$th (and $9$th) line it holds
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\bf{False}&=&\bf{isBinaryTree(T,\; w)}\\
&=&\bf{isBinaryTree(T,\; w.predecessor)}\\
&=&\bf{isBinaryTree(T,\; w.predecessor.predecessor)}\\
&\vdots&\\
&=&\bf{isBinaryTree(T,\; rootT)} \text{.}\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$